# coverswitch, flip-switch is missing from TaskSwitcher

Tags: kde, manjaro, kwin

Everything was working fine. I update my PC last night & found out that task switching defaults to `breeze` scheme.

Though, I don't use other effects available there rather than `flip-switch`(as alternative) and `cover-switch`. Both, seems to be rolled out.

Is there a way to get them back?? Though, I'm not sure if it happens to everyone who uses *kde*. I'm on KDE **(Plasma: 5.23.3, Framework: 5.88.0, Qt: 5.15.2)** over Manjaro.